# Why does the counter inside if statement not work?

Tags: java, if-statement, counter

Hello friends I am trying to build a class Car for a project. There are many methods inside the following code as well as an if statement that I am having trouble building, consider the following code

```
public class Car extends Vehicle {
    private boolean isDriving;
    private final int horsepower;
    private boolean needsMaintenance = false;
    private int tripsSinceMaintenance = 0;

    Car() {
        super();
        this.horsepower = 0;
        this.isDriving = false;
        this.needsMaintenance = false;
        this.tripsSinceMaintenance = 0;
    }

    public int getHorsepower() {
        return this.horsepower;
    }

    public boolean getDrive() {
        return this.isDriving;
    }

    public boolean getMain() {
        return this.needsMaintenance;
    }

    public int getTRIP() {
        return this.tripsSinceMaintenance;
    }

    public void drive() {
        this.isDriving = true;
    }

    public void stop() {
        this.isDriving = false;
    }


    public void repair() {
        this.needsMaintenance = false;
        this.tripsSinceMaintenance = 0;
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Car auto = new Car();
        auto.drive();
        auto.stop();

        if (auto.isDriving == true) {
            if (auto.isDriving == false)
                auto.tripsSinceMaintenance = auto.tripsSinceMaintenance + 1;
        }

        if (auto.tripsSinceMaintenance > 100)
            auto.needsMaintenance = true;
        System.out.println("Drive: " + auto.getDrive());
        System.out.println("trip: " + auto.getTRIP());
    }
}
```

What I want to do is whenever the attribute `isDriving` goes from `true` to `false` the `tripsSinceMaintenance should increase by 1 and also when`  tripsSinceMaintenance`is greater than 100,`needsMaintenance`should become`true`.

here I expected trips to be 1 but the result is the following:

**Drive: false
trip: 0**

I have tried `this.isDriving==true;`  and basicaly wherever    `auto`      is inside the if statement I put     `this`    but the following error appears

non static variable cannot be referenced from static context

help me please!

Comment: You have two nested `if` statements.  Check carefully what the conditions are for each statement and how they interact.

Comment: auto.isDriving cannot be true and false at the same time

Comment: @OldProgrammer you are totally right thanks!!!!

Answer (score 2):

> What i want to do is whenever the attribute isDriving goes from true to false the tripsSinceMaintenance should increase by 1 and also when tripsSinceMaintenance is greater than 100 needsMaintenance should become true

Do this inside stop() method

```
fun stop() {
    if (isDriving) {
        tripsSinceMaintenance++;
    }
    if (tripsSinceMaintenance > 100) {
        needsMaintenance = true;
    }
    isDriving = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to put == true inside of an if statement, it's doing that already,

```
if(someCondition) { // <-- this executes if the condition is true.
```

Also, you have conflicting conditions nested, meaning...

```
if (thisIsTrue) {
    if (!thisIsTrue) { 
        // <--- unreachable statements
```

where you should be incrementing your variable is where you're setting "isDriving = true"
So your code would look like this:

```
public void drive() {
    this.isDriving=true;
    auto.tripsSinceMaintenance++;
}
```